# Is that possible to disallow public access AWS Files, but serve only a specific Origin?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Recently I use *AWS S3 bucket* to serve static files for my Django project.
Here is my settings:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') # 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') # 
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket-name' 
AWS_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

After creating the bucket, I can see these options are by default True

[image]
<sub>(source: [firefoxusercontent.com](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/da90dd17-3e87-4839-881b-3da5f4bee38d.png))</sub>

But when I try to access my static files from my website www.my-site.com or locally 127.0.0.0.1:8000, **it shows 403 permission denied. What do I miss?**

```
Request URL: https://bucket-name.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/static/file-name.js
Request method: GET
Remote address: 52.0.0.0:443
Status code: 403
```

After some searches, I tried to define a CORS like:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: If your django application also running under AWS service ( EC2) make sure you have granted rule to EC2 for accessing to S3.

Comment: can you please specify where to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Attach role to existing/running EC2 instance]

To be able to define IAM role you can select existing instance and attach new role as S3 Access to EC2